# Let $(X, T_x), (Y,T_y)$ be topological space. A map $f:X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)} $

Tags: general-topology

Today in class we proved the following theorem:

Let $(X, T_x), (Y,T_y)$ be topological spaces. A map $f:X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)} $

But now when I'm going through my notes, something in the yellow highlighted part feels wrong, specially the  $f(\overline{A}) = f(f^{-1}(A))$. Can someone verify if my notes are correct, or wrong?

$(\Leftarrow)$
Asssume now that $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)} $ for every $A \in X$. Let $M \subset Y$ be closed and let $A = f^{-1}(M)$. Then

> $f(\overline{A}) = f(f^{-1}(A)) \subset \overline{f(f^{-1}(M))} = \overline{M} = M$

This implies

> $\overline{A} \subset f^{-1}(f(A)) = f^{-1}(M) = A$

Hence $A = \overline{A}$, hence every preimage of a closed set is closed, i.e f continuous.

Comment: No, but $f(\overline{A}) = f(\overline{f^{-1}(A)})$ @mfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first display should read:
$$
f(\overline{A}) = f(\overline{f^{-1}(M)}) \stackrel{(*)}\subset \overline{f(f^{-1}(M))} = \overline{M} = M\tag1
$$
because by assumption $A=f^{-1}(M)$. The set inclusion $(*)$ follows from the other assumption $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$. It might be clearer to argue:
$$
f(\overline{A})  \stackrel{(*)}\subset \overline{f(A)}=\overline{f(f^{-1}(M))} = \overline{M} = M\tag1
$$

And, BTW, your second display should read:
$$
\overline{A} \subset f^{-1}(f(\overline A)) \stackrel{(1)}\subset f^{-1}(M) = A
$$

Comment: Just to justify, the second on is correct, right?

Comment: Nope, see my edit

Comment: Couldn't the second line aswell be $\overline{A} = f^{-1}(f(\overline{A})) \subset \dots$?

Comment: It's not true that $B=f^{-1}(f(B))$ for every $B$. For example try $f(x):=1$ and $B=\{0\}$. The best you can say is $B\subset f^{-1}(f(B))$.

Comment: @grand_chat I agree but I think $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subset B$ for every $B \subset Y$ is more relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple error when copying the first step.  It should read 
$$
f(\overline{A}) = f(\overline{f^{-1}(M)}) = \overline{f(f^{-1}(M)})
$$
where the first equality is justified by $A = f^{-1}(M)$